# Autocompleter for custom textfield in joomla

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete, joomla, mootools

I have a textfield in a component i am using. I want to implement autocompleter for that field. Also the autocompleter should fetch data from an array...I tried the autocompleter with mootools from the below link but it works when tested seperately but when i integrate it with joomla it doesnt work. 
http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/

Can anyone suggest me what are the options i can go after to fulfill my requirement. ??? or wat could be the cause that its not working.

Using Jquery might result in conflict with mootools so havnt tried that option.....

Thank you for the reply...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that Joomla renders response as HTML not JSON. Try to open the URL which you use for autocompletion in browser and see page source.

How to render valid JSON or XML, you can read in [Joomla Wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/Ajax_using_MooTools), sections "Generating JSON output" and "Generating XML output" respectively